# Failed to install pykaldi on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, numpy, kaldi

I followed the instructions and ran the following to commands to install pykaldi:

```
git clone https://github.com/pykaldi/pykaldi.git
cd pykaldi
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake cmake curl g++ git graphviz libatlas3-base libtool make pkg-config subversion unzip wget zlib1g-dev
sudo apt install intel-mkl-64bit-2020.4-912
python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
python3.7 -m pip install numpy pyparsing ninja==1.10.0
cd tools
sudo torify ./check_dependencies.sh /usr/bin/python3.7
sudo torify ./install_protobuf.sh /usr/bin/python3.7
sudo torify ./install_clif.sh /usr/bin/python3.7
sudo torify ./install_kaldi.sh
cd ..
python3.7 -m pip install setuptools 
sudo apt-get install ninja-build
sudo python3.7 setup.py install
```

when it comes to the last line, I get the following error:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pykaldi.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pykaldi.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to pykaldi.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to pykaldi.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'pykaldi.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'pykaldi.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Using PYCLIF: /usr/local/bin/pyclif
Using CLIF_MATCHER: /usr/clang/bin/clif-matcher
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/soroushh/KhodnevisProjects/wav2vec-u/pykaldi/build
[6/505] Building CXX object kaldi/matrix/CMakeFiles/_matrix_ext.dir/matrix-ext.cc.o
FAILED: kaldi/matrix/CMakeFiles/_matrix_ext.dir/matrix-ext.cc.o 
/usr/bin/c++  -D_matrix_ext_EXPORTS -I../kaldi/lib -I../kaldi -Ikaldi -I../tools/kaldi/src -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/home/soroushh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -std=c++11 -I.. -isystem /home/soroushh/KhodnevisProjects/wav2vec-u/pykaldi/tools/kaldi/tools/openfst-1.6.7/include -O1 -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Winit-self -DKALDI_DOUBLEPRECISION=0 -DHAVE_EXECINFO_H=1 -DHAVE_CXXABI_H -DHAVE_MKL -I/opt/intel/mkl/include -m64 -msse -msse2 -pthread -g -fPIC -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fPIC -MD -MT kaldi/matrix/CMakeFiles/_matrix_ext.dir/matrix-ext.cc.o -MF kaldi/matrix/CMakeFiles/_matrix_ext.dir/matrix-ext.cc.o.d -o kaldi/matrix/CMakeFiles/_matrix_ext.dir/matrix-ext.cc.o -c ../kaldi/matrix/matrix-ext.cc
In file included from /home/soroushh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:4:0,
                 from /home/soroushh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                 from /home/soroushh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from ../kaldi/matrix/matrix-ext.cc:8:
/home/soroushh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_common.h:386:9: error: ‘Py_hash_t’ does not name a type
 typedef Py_hash_t npy_hash_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/soroushh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:0,
                 from /home/soroushh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from ../kaldi/matrix/matrix-ext.cc:8:
/home/soroushh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:655:9: error: ‘npy_hash_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘npy_half’?
         npy_hash_t hash;
         ^~~~~~~~~~
         npy_half
[11/505] Building CXX object kaldi/chain/CMakeFiles/_chain_generic_numerator.dir/chain-generic-numerator-clifwrap.cc.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Command '['ninja', '-j', '6']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I also tried different versions of PyKaldi, i.e. 1.8.0 and 1.10.0. But it shows the same error.

Edit 1: when I execute `/usr/bin/ninja -j 6` I get the following error: ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory